# Bulma navbar example with menu toggle not leading to desired result

Tags: html, css, bulma

I am having troubles getting the navbar working the way I want. I am working with the newest bulma.io css file. In general I see that the bulma page itself shows a little bit different from my Chrome window ... not all the examples are working like the text say they would.

So I tried cooking it down, all I want in the end is a logo left and dropdown plus a button right:

[image: expected]

So reduced the code to try that

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.4/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>test</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      

<nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
   <div class="navbar-brand">
      <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io">
         <img src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png" width="112" height="28">
      </a>

   </div>

 
   <div class="navbar-end">
      <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
         <a class="navbar-link">
            More
         </a>
         <div class="navbar-dropdown is-boxed">
            <a class="navbar-item">
               test
            </a>
            <a class="navbar-item">
               test 2
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-item">
      <div class="buttons">
         <a class="button is-primary">
            <strong>Sign up</strong>
         </a>
         <a class="button is-light">
            Log in
         </a>
      </div>
      </div>
   </div>
 </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

but I got:

[image]

(the button on "More" to toggle the menu does not work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Add the below CSS styles in your code.

```css
.navbar{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
.navbar-end{
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.4/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>test</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      

<nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
   <div class="navbar-brand">
      <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io">
         <img src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png" width="112" height="28">
      </a>

   </div>

 
   <div class="navbar-end">
      <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
         <a class="navbar-link">
            More
         </a>
         <div class="navbar-dropdown is-boxed">
            <a class="navbar-item">
               test
            </a>
            <a class="navbar-item">
               test 2
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-item">
      <div class="buttons">
         <a class="button is-primary">
            <strong>Sign up</strong>
         </a>
         <a class="button is-light">
            Log in
         </a>
      </div>
      </div>
   </div>
 </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: shouldn't bulma do this by itself?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some code.

```
<div class="navbar-menu">
    <div class="navbar-end">
        <!-- your existing code can be copied here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

navbar-menu is crucial, even if you dont use the "mobile" version of the menu. Even without  adding  will make it so you dont need to use the CSS mentioned above.